# Can I package multiple Liferay portlets and a themes in a WAR file?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I can easily create Liferay portlets and themes individually using the Liferay plugin SDK. I have managed to combine multiple portlets into one WAR file which has been pretty convenient for deployment at client sites.

I have also created multiple themes for my Liferay installation and I was wondering if it's possible to combine all the portlets(5) and themes(2) ( perhaps hooks etc ) into one WAR file?

Comment: You can combine themes into one WAR, and portlets+hooks into the other AFIAK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont think theme and portlets can be packaged together and it shouldnt be packaged together for better maintenance.

You can always package portlet and hook together in a single plugin project. I normally do it if the functionality in hook is tied with the portlet, otherwise I keep it separate.